# AngularJS if user chooses year/month/week resolution on Dropdown1, populate Dropdown2 with the corresponding values

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, selection

I'm trying to do the following task:
Say that we have a dropdown (Dropdown1) that includes the options {year, month, week, day}. We also have Dropdown2, that changes according to what is chosen in Dropdown1.

So if user chooses 'year', Dropdown2 will have the years {2013,2014,2015}. If user chooses 'month',  Dropdown2 will have all the months from 2013 to today {Jan 2013,Feb 2013...Jan 2015} and same goes for the days. I've managed to do this only for the 'year' case..

I do not want to use Datepicker, I just want to do this simply and efficiently.
Here's how it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an ng-change directive to your resolution list, and call a method to generate values used for the period list.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

--

Another option would be to generate all 4 period lists ahead of time:

```
$scope.periodLists = {
    year: [...list of years...], 
    month: [...list of month+years...], 
    week: [...], 
    day: [...]
};
```

Then your periods dropdown list ng-model would be bound using the option from the resolution list.  Something like:

```
ng-model="periodList[selectedResolution]"
```

When user picks a different resolution, the second list switches to periodList[year] or periodList[month] ...

Comment: This is useful when it comes to binding the two dropdowns. My main concern is how to dynamically populate the dropdown. I could do it using a list in the controller that would contain several dates, and according to what user chooses some of them would be displayed, but this is not dynamic..

Comment: Edited answer to explain another solution.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but still I cannot see how I could obtain the days/months without having to create a list. I want the program to 'understand' when a day or month passes and include it to the second dropdown.Maybe by using moment.js, but I do not have the skills to do so yet.